# Como chamar uma conexão dentro de uma função?

Tags: php, mysqli

```
<?php
define('HOST', 'localhost');
define('USER', 'root');
define('PASS', '');
define('DBNAME', 'soufood');

try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.HOST.';dbname='.DBNAME.';',USER, PASS);
}catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

function ExibirCarrinho(){
    $exibirCarrinho = "SELECT * FROM carrinho";
    $exibirCarrinho = $conn->prepare($exibirCarrinho);
    $exibirCarrinho->execute();
      while ($row = $exibirCarrinho->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

      }
}
?>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Passa a conexão como parâmetro.

Comment: Show! Obrigado amigo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao declarar a função dessa forma você está dizendo que ela receberá um parâmetro.

**Declarando a função.**

```
function ExibirCarrinho($parametro)
{
    $exibirCarrinho = "SELECT * FROM carrinho";
    $exibirCarrinho = $parametro->prepare($exibirCarrinho);
    $exibirCarrinho->execute();
      while ($row = $exibirCarrinho->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
      {

      }
}
```

Ao chamar a função, você passa a sua instância da conexão ($conn) por parâmetro.

**Chamando a função:**

```
ExibirCarrinho($conn);
```

**OBS:** Mudei o nome da sua variável da função para "$parametro" só pra demonstração mesmo.

**OBS 2:** Segundo a PSR-1, nomes de métodos e funções devem ter a primeira letra minúscula. Ref: [PHP-FIG](https://www.php-fig.org/)

Comment: Caraca! Muito obrigado amigo.

Comment: Foi nada, @KauanDouglas . O Augusto já tinha te falado isso no comentário. Boa sorte !